# Viewing crash logs on Android tablet (HTC Flyer)

Tags: android, logging, tablet, crash-reports

I'm experiencing application crashes on my HTC Flyer tablet, which runs the Android operating system. In order to properly debug these crashes—or even know where to *start* debugging—I need to know the reason for these crashes.

Where can I find the log files that are created by applications? Do I need to install any special software on my device to ensure that these log files are created and/or accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most developers that have the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) installed use logcat to view the stored buffer of logs.  From a command line you can run 'adb logcat' with your device connected to dump this log.

If you have Eclipse and the Android Device Tools (ADT) plugin, you can select the DDMS tab in Eclipse, select the process of interest and then view the LogCat window for logs.

If you have neither, you can do a catalog search for CatLog which is an app that allows viewing this data on the handset.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Install the USB drivers for your device (http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html)
3. In the platform-tools folder in the SDK directory, call "adb logcat"

*or*

Install log collector on your device (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector) and let the app create the log for you.